# getting result code from posting on facebook activity

Tags: android, facebook

I am trying to do a share url link on facebook via my android app. below is the code.
Question, I need to be able to detect if the post is successful, or user cancel or some other error, I am able to post, but i am not able to get anything in return. ie.  onActivityResult is never going to be called. What have i missed out?  Thanks.

```
public static void openFacebook(Activity activity, View view, String urlToShare) {

        //String urlToShare = "www.korvac.com";

        Intent shareIntent = new Intent();
        shareIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        shareIntent.setType("text/plain");
        shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, urlToShare);
        // See if official Facebook app is found
        boolean facebookAppFound = false;
        List<ResolveInfo> matches = activity.getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities(
                shareIntent, 0);
        for (ResolveInfo info : matches) {

            if (info.activityInfo.packageName.startsWith("com.facebook.katana")) {
                // "com.facebook.katana" is the package name for Facebook app
                // "com.facebook.orca" is for FB Messenger app
                shareIntent.setPackage(info.activityInfo.packageName);
                facebookAppFound = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        // As fallback, launch sharer.php in a browser
        if (!facebookAppFound) {
            String sharerUrl = "https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u="
                    + urlToShare;
            shareIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(sharerUrl));
        }

        activity.startActivityForResult(shareIntent, 90);

    }

    /* Called when the second activity's finished */
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        switch(requestCode) {
        case 90:
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                Bundle res = data.getExtras();
                String result = res.getString("param_result");
                Log.d("facebook", "result:"+result);
            }
            else{
                Log.d("facebook", "result:"+ "failed");
            }
            break;
        }
    }
```

Comment: ACTION_VIEW intents do not return a result, that's the status quo for Android intents.

Comment: then any alternative way to do this? post a link, image or text on facebook but able to return if it is successfully posted? Thanks.

Comment: You can use the Share Dialog as provided by the Facebook SDK. However, even with the share dialog, you will only receive the result if the user has given your app publish permissions. Why do you want to know what the user has done?

Comment: because i am doing an point rewarding application, it will award users points if they do share a link on their fb (if the posting is a successful one). I have imported in the SDK, but still stuck in getting app id for the sdk. I just need to be able to know if the post is successful, does the sdk able to do so?

Comment: You can't incentivize like that, it would be against platform policies. See section 4.5 https://developers.facebook.com/policy#properuse